# MySql: "Accessed denied for user 'root'@'<remote-ip> (using password: YES)" from my Laptop, BUT NOT my coworkers?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I set up a VM (RHEL6) in our company's private cloud, and installed MySQL.

I opened up remote connections like the following so my coworkers and I could connect to it:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbname`.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Here is the result from `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';`

```
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbname`.* TO 'root'@'%' |
```

1) My coworker can connect to it from the mysql client on his laptop via

```
mysql -h <hostname> -u root -p dbname
```

2) I can create a separate VM and connect to the original VM using the same syntax.

However, on my laptop, I can not connect to it. I receive the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'<my-ip>' (using passwo
rd: YES)
```

I've even specifically opened it for my IP using `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON`dbname`.* TO 'root'@'<my-ip>'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`, which of course shouldn't be necessary, but it didn't work.

I have restarted the MySQL server (which wasn't necessary for my coworkers).

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried disabling any firewalls on your machine, and the VM? Sometimes cloud providers or even private companies will put an "upstream firewall" in front of your VM/VPS and not tell you.

Comment: @DarthCaniac My Windows Firewall was already disabled, but I'll look into seeing if my company has installed a separate firewall and see what I can do about it. What I don't get, however, is how my coworkers are all able to connect-- they said they didn't mess with any firewalls.

Comment: I've got this same issue (though I'm not able to connect from another IP on the same network)

Comment: @BFigueiredo I think I rage quit, deleted the VM, reinstalled and it worked after, IIRC.

Comment: In my case, passwords were not set on each new user definition: solution here: http://serverfault.com/a/230018